# Implementing String class c++

Tags: c++, string, class

I am trying to implement a String class in c++. I am trying to overload the "==" operator, I keep getting these errors:

**error C2676: binary '[': 'const MyString' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator"**

and

**error C2088: '[': illegal for class**

```
bool operator==(const MyString& str1, const MyString& str2) {

int i;
for (i=0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if (str1[i] != str2[i]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: The problem is what the error says.  Your class does not implement the [] operator and you're trying to use it.

Comment: How is the rest of the class implemented? Did you overload the `[]` operator?

Comment: You probably should be using the subscript on the member of your class that holds the contents of the string, not on the class itself.

Comment: If you could get a *more* descriptive error message than that, I'm pressed to see how. Maybe you defined `operator[]` for your class, but forgot to provide a `const` version? or maybe you didn't provide one at all. Since you've not provided any other details, the best you'll get is a wild guess.

Comment: Does your class have a `operator[]`?

Comment: And it is possible that you could access out of bounds of str2. Your for loop conditional should check both of the strings for end of string.

Comment: @SelçukCihan Actually, that can't happen. If `str2` is shorter than `str1`, its trailing null character will not match the non-null character at that position in `str1`, so it will return `false`.

Comment: There's a different bug: if `str1` is a prefix of `str2`, the function will return `true`.

Comment: @OP.  If your class has a `size` member that denotes the number of characters in the string, and you're allowed to use `memcmp`, and you have access to the string's buffer, you really don't need to use `operator [ ]`, and the function becomes 3 lines -- `{ if (str1.size() != str2.size()) return false; return memcmp(str1.buffer, str2.buffer, str1.size()) == 0;}`

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you have not written an implementation for the `[]` operator. Try something like this, inside your `MyString` class:

```
char& operator[](int index){
    //return character value at given index, perform bounds checking if you like
}
```

Comment: `size_t` would be better.